# Fatal error: Declaration of Foo::__toString(): void must be compatible with Stringable::__toString(): string

Tags: php, magic-methods, php-8

After upgrading to PHP 8 I'm now seeing this `Fatal error` what's wrong with my code ? And what is this `Stringable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to PHP 8 it was possible for a programmer to write magic methods that have signatures that don't match the internal signature of them.

So for example

```
class Foo {
    public function __toString(): void {
    
    }
}
```

Although the return type `void` doesn't match the method's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring)

```
public __toString ( void ) : string
```

PHP was not complaining!

However, with the advent of PHP 8 the signature of a magic method must follow that magic method's documentation.

```
public function __toString(): string {

}
```

Otherwise you'll see a `Fatal error`!

**Note:** The `__construct()` and `__destruct()` are excluded from this new change, since there is not concept of them returning values in almost every computer language.

---

#### What is this Stringable?

`Stringable` is an interface that is added automatically to classes that implement the `__toString()` method

See the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/stringable) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You must refactor your function `__toString()` from:

```
public function __toString(): void {
  //definition
}
```

to function returning `string` value.

```
public function __toString(): string {
  //definition
  return 'some string';
}
```